# Change 'Download URL' to 'Search URL' XML Data

Tags: javascript, xml

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/searchsites.html) page, which will give the user functionality to load markers with the selection or deselection of checkboxes. They will then be able to click on these markers which in turn shows the nearest POI within a given radius.

The problem I'm having is with loading the xml at lines 143-145 which are:

```
downloadUrl("loadmylocations.php", function(data) {  
var xml = data.responseXML; 
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker")
```

Firefox tells me that the error is that the 'xml is undefined'. I think I know why and that's because I'm using this code to pull data for the POI's.

```
    var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
    var searchUrl = 'searchsites.php?siteosgb36lat=' + center.lat() + '&siteosgb36lon=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = parseXml(data);
```

So they clash, because I define the XML at the end of the script differently, these being

**loadmylocations.php**

```
    request.open('GET', url, true); 
    request.send(null); 
    } 

    function doNothing() {}
```

**searchsites.php**

```
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
            }

            function parseXml(str) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.loadXML(str);
            return doc;
            } else if (window.DOMParser) {
            return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
            }
            }

            function doNothing() {}
```

Could someone perhaps tell me please how I can change so that I can pull the two sets of data wihtin the same script without them clashing.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some work around this, and through trial and error I discovered that I could load the information for the 'loadmylocations' script as the 'searchsites' script i.e.  var xml = parseXml(data); rather than var xml = data.responseXML;.